# sphinix library failed to import in project

Tags: java, swing, pocketsphinx

I'm creating an Speech Recognition application in Java swing using Sphinx. I've downloaded sphinx from git hub and included the zip file in my library.But, can't able to use it in my project.I've already worked with another project using sphinx but in that project sphinx is imported as .jar file and that can be used. But, as a zip file I can't use. How to use it as zip file?

Thank you in advance!

I've tried to use sphinx library as zip file.But, I can't use it as zip but I can use it as a jar file.But, I need to use it as a zip not as a jar file

Comment: Unzip the zip file.  I suspect the JAR file is a part of the zip file.